# Read dataset with URL link in R

Tags: r, url, hyperlink, dataset

I would like to read in R the following dataset from this link(https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-2001-to-present/ijzp-q8t2). I tried to display the dataset in text format or csv format, but I have not been able to to it. Also, the file is too big to be contained in only one Excel CSV file. I am interested toward the observations from 2015. My purpose is to built some code that could be execute by anyone who have access to Internet. That's why I want to extract and manipulate the dataset by some command lines on R.

I have been working on this for many hours. Any hints or solutions would be really appreciate.

Comment: patience is key here and i think you may be better off with a plain `curl` vs R but it should work in R (perhaps try `httr::GET` with `write_disk()` or the `curl` package. I registered for the site and was able to download the 2015 subset in a cpl minutes.  2001 to present is at 128MB and still d/l (and it's not a speedy d/l from their servers). The CSV link works fine but you can also try the `RSocrata` package which is designed for SODA URLs. It's going to take a while regardless of the mechanism you choose.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How did you select the 2015 subset? Did you used a R command? I tried the following code, but it's very long: ` `library(curl)
ChicagoCrimes <- read.csv(curl("https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/ijzp-q8t2/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD") )`Do you think that it works?

Comment: i filtered on 2015 manually and copied the new URL since the 2001+ d/l was taking _forever_ (literally) and was approaching 200+MB (prbly wld have been just shy of 500MB).